# Angular 5 routerLink between parent component and other parent - child component

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

There are 2 separate modules in an Angular 5 application named as core and admin.

The core routing is set up as :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './../admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    data: {
      expectedRole: Constants.ADMIN_ROLE_ID
    }
  },
];
```

Now, within the admin module, the routing is as :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'activity',
        children: [
          { path: '', component: ActivityComponent },
          { path: 'detail/:id', component: ActivityDetailComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: UserComponent },
             { path: 'detail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },
        ]
    }
];
```

**Objective**

If the application page is at `"http:localhost/admin/activity"`, I need to add a **routerLink** to an HTML element so that the app navigates to `"http:localhost/admin/user/detail/1"`.

**What I have tried**

`[routerLink]="['user/detail', id]` but this takes the app to `"http://localhost/admin/activity/user/detail/1"`.

**Expected output**

`"http:localhost/admin/user/detail/1"`.

**Please note**

The `admin` keyword in the route is dynamic and I do not wish to hard code this in the `routerLink`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved as changing your admin-routing.module.ts file as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminComponent 
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'activity',
                    component: ActivityComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'view',
                            component: ActivityViewComponent
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'detail/:id',
                            component: ActivityDetailComponent
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                path: 'user',
                component: UserComponent,
                children: [
                        {
                            path: 'view',
                            component: UserViewComponent
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'detail/:id',
                            component: UserDetailComponent
                        }
                    ]
                }
        ]
    }
];
```

You can see two new components: **UserViewComponent** and **ActivityViewComponent**, which simply used for the view of your current UserComponent and ActivityComponent respectively.

Replace the content of *user.component.html* (place it in user-view.component.html) and *activity.component.html* (place it in activity-view.component.html) by `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` which is very important in this task.

Now you can access these components as

- /admin/activity/view
- /admin/activity/detail/:id
- /admin/user/view
- /admin/user/detail/:id

You can find more details [here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-child-routes-and-relative-navigation-example)

Comment: I understand that this is one way to do it but I am more interested to do this while maintaining the children routes. I think routerLink is capable to handle regex to probably solve this issue.

Comment: Okay. I have looked around on google but did not find anything. What do you suggest?

Comment: I ended up doing what you had earlier suggested.

Answer (score 0):

He try this one

```
   const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'activity',
            children: [
              { path: '', component: ActivityComponent },
              { path: 'detail/:id', component: ActivityDetailComponent }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'user',
            children: [
                { path: '', component: UserComponent },
                 { path: 'detail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },
            ]
        }
    ];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**RouterModule.forChild(routes)** use to handle other route modules